# Should I use Celery or Carrot for a Django project?

Tags: python, django, message-queue, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm a little confused as to which one I should use. I think either will work, but is one better or more appropriate than the other?

http://github.com/ask/carrot/tree/master

http://github.com/ask/celery/tree/master

Comment: Hmm, which one is preferred by pink ponies? ;-)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you need to send/receive messages to/from AMQP message queues, use `carrot`.

If you want to run scheduled tasks on a number of machines, use `celery`.

If you're making soup, use both ;-)

Comment: I was searching in google for anything like "Soup" related to task queue framework .. funny names!!

Comment: Isn't your explanation a little bit simplistic? How about celery worker - easy management, configuration, startup scripts, rate limits etc.

Answer (score 7):

May you should see this http://www.slideshare.net/idangazit/an-introduction-to-celery